# How to update woocommerce_after_order_notes when address changes?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Before anything, thank you in advance for your help.

I have a woocommercer store. I have set up a field for the clients to choose the delivery date they prefer with add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'elige_fecha_entrega' );

The delivery options depend on the shipping zone. For certain zones the have certain days available. All this code is fine and it works. My next question is how to make the content change dynamically if the client changes its address.

I mean, how could I add a trigger so when the address changes my action runs again so the options are updated without refreshing the page (which is what they have to do now).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JavaScript/jQuery. For instance use the `updated_checkout` trigger. `$( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', yourFunctionHere );`

Comment: I get "elige_fecha_entrega" (this is my function): not an object